# What is the difference between a View and a PartialView in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view

What is the difference between a View and a PartialView in ASP.NET MVC?

At first glance the need for both seems non-obvious to me.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

In theory, the answer is:  *A partial view is a "sub-view" that you embed within a main view - something that you might reuse across multiple views, like a sidebar.*

In practice, the answer is:  **Very little.**

In theory, partial views are more lightweight than standard views, but it's perfectly OK to pass a "regular" view to `RenderPartial` and the performance seems to be exactly the same.  I frequently use regular .aspx views as "partial" views because you can make them reference a master view in order to provide templated content like what you can do with UserControls in ASP.NET WebForms.  See [here](http://jeffreypalermo.com/blog/asp-net-mvc-and-the-templated-partial-view-death-to-ascx/).

Partial views are more like web parts on a portal - they are completely self-contained objects.  Use them if the layout is simple and static, or if you're annoyed by the Intellisense errors when you don't have the `<html>` and `<body>` tags in a standard View.

Comment: how about return View() and return PartialView(), it seems to me that there is no difference at all

Answer (score 11):

It works like that:

- return View() the view content goes in the @RenderBody() of the /Shared/_Layout.cshtml
- return PartialView() it returns only the view content

Answer (score 6):

Views are the general result of a page that results in a display.  It's the highest level container except the masterpage.  While a partial view is for a small piece of content that may be reused on different pages, or multiple times in a page.

If you're coming from webforms, view is similar to a web content form, while a partial view is like a user control.

Answer (score 3):

If you come from a webforms background, think of PartialView as a usercontrol.

Answer (score 3):

Look at StackOverflow.com site:
Main site (View) contains components like:

- Tags
- Related
- Ad

So Tags, related, Ad etc. can be composed as PartialViews. The advantage of this is that 
PartialViews can be simply cached by OutputCache instead of recreating all site: performance gain.

Comment: But, you could presumably envisage a system that simply enables "Views" to contain "Views", negating the need for an additional type?

Comment: View that contains other Views is very handy. It's depend of you and it's you choice to have one big View or one View as set of smaller Views. All partial views should be independent of others and can have other types as return values.

Answer (score 2):

Consider a partialview like a control in webforms, the idea is the partial is reusable

Answer (score 0):

### View in Core Mvc

- View Contains The layout Page(_ViewStart) Or Layout Property.

> @{
> Layout="_Layout";   }

- Before Any View Rendered _ViewStart is Rendered.
- View might have markup tags As

> ```
> <!DOCTYPE html>   
>  <html>
>      <head>
>      </head>
>      <body>    
>      </body> 
>   </html>
> ```

- View isn't Lightwight as Partial View.
- View will Render in Layout by used @RenderBody() Method
  (Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml).
- Calling by use return View() inside Action.

---

### Partial View

- Partial view doesn't Contain Layout Page **Layout Property**
- It does not verify for a viewstart.cshtml. We cannot put common code
  for a partial view within the viewStart.cshtml.page.
- In MVC Partial view is designed specially to render within the view
- We can pass a regular view to the RenderPartial method.

> @{await Html.PartialAsync("Partial"); }

**Example To Demo Partial View Is Strongly Type**

> in View
>
> ```
> @model List<Student>;
> @{
>     Layout = "_Layout";
> }  
>  
> <div>@await Html.PartialAsync("Partial",Model)</div>
> ```
>
> in Partial View
>
> ```
> @model List<Student>; <ul>
>      @foreach (Student student in Model)
>      {
>         <li>@student.ID</li>
>         <li>@student.Name</li>
>         <li>@student.Age</li>
>      }
>  
>      </ul>
> ```

- SP.NET Core MVC looks for Partial View in the same way like Regular
  Views (i.e. in Views/ and Views/Shared folders). This
  means you can create controller specific partial views or shared
  partial views.

  *Good Luck*