# Dynamic partial view + jquery form hijack + client validation = not working

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation, dynamic, partial-views

I'm using MVC 3 with unobtrusive javascript for client validation.

I have a table with rows which are clickable. When clicked I want to bring up a dynamically loaded partial view. This is the code for this:

```
function GetStuff(id) {
    $.ajax(
    {
        url: "Edit/" + id,
        success: function (result) {
            $("#DivTest").html(result);
        }
    });
}
```

This far everything works.
The problem is when I'm trying to save something in the partial using jquery. The form is hijacked, like this:

```
$(function () {
    $.post($(this).attr("action"),
        $(this).serialize(),
        function (data) {
            alert("test");
        });
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

This all together makes the client validation not work. It just makes the post even if I have left out some required values. This all works if I'm not using ajax to post or if the partial is loaded on page load (not dynamic).

---

What I've tried:

I tried putting this before the post:

```
if($('form').validate().form()){
    ...
}
```

This just returns true every time though..

From this post i got 2 suggestions 
[ASP.NET MVC 2 loading partial view using jQuery - no client side validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2652586/asp-net-mvc-2-loading-partial-view-using-jquery-no-client-side-validation)

Adding

```
Sys.Mvc.FormContext._Application_Load();
```

after the partial has been loaded.. 
And set the datatype of the post to "html". Neither worked.

I also tried this method with no luck:
http://www.deepcode.co.uk/2010/08/mvc-ootb-validation-when-pulling-in.html

This combination of techniques are something very common I guess, why is it so hard to make it work? Any help is highly appreciated. 
Thank you

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Upon the successfull ajax load of the new form you have to instruct the unobtrusive validation library to parse the new form by manually calling:

```
// insert new form into the DOM first, then call:
$.validator.unobtrusive.parse('<form selector>'));
$('<form selector>').validate(); // start validating
```

This sets up the jquery.validation validators according to the data-xxx attribute in the forms child elements.

After that the call `$('<form selector>').validate().form()`  should work as expected!

Comment: This works very well. I guess it's better than the solution I just came up with (adding the js file in the partial view). It feels much better to mark another persons answer as correct also than my own :)

Comment: tnx, well this is technically what the unobtrusive validation script registers in a $(document).ready() handler. so my solution and your solution execute the same code :)

Comment: This answered an issue I was having as well.  However, it's validating  the new form (and failing on every field, since its empty) which is not optimal.  Any ideas why it's doing this/how to stop it?

Answer (score 1):

Why are you trying to hijack the partial form? I *think* because your hijacking the form the unobtrusive live events are not firing and thats why your not getting validation errors.

Have you tried using an Ajax form? `(Ajax.BeginForm(...))`

If you bring in a partial ajax form this should have all the information needed for validation. Once the form is submitted you can specify a javascript function to run.

Comment: I've read several posts recommending not to use any MS ajax methods, but instead use jquery, especially if everything else is done with jquery.. I tried this though but the events are not firing (like "OnBegin" and "OnSuccess". Instead the page is posted returning _only_ the partial view for itself.

Comment: In MVC 3 the ajax has been changed to use jquery and IMO been improved greatly. How are your returning your results once you've posted to the action? Are you returning a Json result? If not try that. That way you can then parse the json in your jquery onsuccess and determin what to do.

Comment: I'm returning a PartialView(model) but I don't mind returning json and parse the result. I tried this now, but the event isn't called anyway so I cant handle the result. I set these parameters in BeginForm: OnBegin, OnSuccess, OnComplete, OnFailure, HttpMethod = "post". But none of the events are working.

Comment: What do your javascript function look like? e.g. does the OnSuccess match the jquery ajax signature so it will look something like function OnSuccess(data, textStatus, jqXHR)? See: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/. Can you post your code if its still not working.

Comment: Its just function OnComplete(content){ alert("test") } But it never gets called. I tested without parameter and with those you suggested. No events are called :( The page is posted and the page is replaced with my Json result string.

Comment: are you including jquery.unobtrusive.min.js in your page?

Comment: I included jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js (didnt have the one you mentioned) and this made the ajax post work with events, thank you! The client validation doesn't work though, is there anything that has to be done here? The model state is invalid now atleast and i can return false, but I would rather have the client validation before posting. Thank you for beeing so patient and helpful Simon.

Comment: I found the answer, but I want to thank you anyway for enlightening me about Ajax.BeginForm, I'll be using it from now on. This wasn't the issue though (see answer).

Answer (score 0):

Ok finally I got it. The problem was there, no matter if I hi jacked the form or if I used Ajax.BeginForm(...), no difference there. And it always worked if I didn't loaded the partial dynamically.

**The solution?**

Add jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js to the **partial** view.
This might be a newbie mistake, adding it only to the parent view or a master page, but if this  helps someone I'll gladly admit this mistake of mine :)
It's this js file that makes the client validation work and it must of course be called every time a partial (that has client validation in it) is loaded.