# ASP.NET MVC: making MicrosoftMvcValidation.js work with dynamically created controls

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-2

I'm currently using MicrosoftMvcValidation.js to do client-side validation on a large web application we're developing. It works fine up until the point where we start adding controls after the page loads.

**What will I have to do to validate dynamically created controls using Microsoft's solution?**

I see that the call to `OutputClientValidation()` is responsible for writing the json string after the form is rendered. I was wondering if I could somehow use some code in there to add to the script at the bottom whenever I add a new control, but I have no idea where to start...

**Note:** My dynamic controls are not loaded asynchronously, I'm just writing html using javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your problem is that the page has allready loaded and in which case the page does not have code that validates it...

you might have a look at 
[Dynamic partial view + jquery form hijack + client validation = not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968575/dynamic-partial-view-jquery-form-hijack-client-validation-not-working)