# How to create tabs view in ASP.NET MVC3 with Razor?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, tabs

I am developing a web application in ASP.NET MVC3 with C# and Razor. I need to create tabs within my web page, exactly as it is displayed in browsers.

I don't know if there is already a template made available by MVC3 or creating tabs is an easier task than I think. Actually it is the first time ever I've been asked to do it.

Anybody has some advice or suggestion? At the beginning I plan to do it with postbacks in order not to lose too much time with jQuery or other client technologies. Thank you very much :D

Comment: jQuery is very much part of the MVC3 ecosystem. You'll benefit from learning it!

Comment: Embrace the jquery! And if I am not mistaken, in MVC there is no such thing as a postback, at least semantically. You click on links (request) and something happens (response) which may include going to the same page you're on currently. Statelessness is our friend.

Comment: @MrBoJangles Exactly.  MVC is all around low-level GETs and POSTs.

Comment: thanks for your comments, maybe I misused postbacks, what I meant was to send back the request to the server synchronously without using any AJAX-based technique. I love jQuery as well but first of all I need to show functionality to the users and than the last step is to adopt client based technologies to improve users'experience

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In my opinion, the time you'd "lose" from learning jQuery (depending on your familiarity with JavaScript/jQuery) would be well worth the time you'd spend on having to play around with the HTML and CSS to get decent looking tabs.

The [jQuery UI Tabs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/) are easy to set up, and very responsive and nice to look at.

Comment: I thougth jQuery was the most complex solution but as far as I can see it is the only feasible option. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 2):

The default templates from MVC have a simple tab system in place for navigation that is based on simple css.

You should have a look at those.  I know that you said that you wanted to avoid jQuery for this, but they don't have  a significant learning curve and there are hundreds of examples of their use on the web.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/ in conjunction with PartialViewResults and jquery ajax can be a powerful tool.
[ASP.NET MVC 2 loading partial view using jQuery - no client side validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2652586/asp-net-mvc-2-loading-partial-view-using-jquery-no-client-side-validation)

Comment: Tabs?  That's more like navigation buttons.  I don't know if that'd qualify as "tabs", persay.