# What is difference between view and partial view in MVC 3?

Tags: .net

what is exact difference in MVC3- view and partial view?

Comment: Also,there are a lot same question in this site... one of them:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2043394/what-is-the-difference-between-a-view-and-a-partialview-in-asp-net-mvc

Answer (score 0):

A partial view is a subcomponent of a full view. It is meant to replace a repetitive component found in multiple locations in your site. A way of looking at it is that it is the visual equivalent of a function.