# navigation bar gets duplicated in Body element MVC

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, razor

As soon as I select a tab in my navigational bar, the navigational bar gets duplicated in the body element.

My navigational bar sits in a Partial page.

Here is my main MVC 5 Layout page:

```
<body>
    @{Html.RenderPartial("_NavBar");}
    <div class="container" id="MainBody">
        @RenderBody()
    </div>
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", false)
</body>
```

Here is my partial page containing the navigation bar:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header" id="nav">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">EDR-Web</a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active">@Ajax.ActionLink("Login", "Index", "Login", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "get", UpdateTargetId = "MainBody", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace })</li>
                <li>@Ajax.ActionLink("Contact Us", "Index", "Contact", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "get", UpdateTargetId = "MainBody", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace })</li>
                <li>@Ajax.ActionLink("Terms Of Use", "Index", "Terms", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "get", UpdateTargetId = "MainBody", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace })</li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>

            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It is worth mentioning that I am using the @Ajax.ActionLink to only update the ID=MainBody on the Main Layout page.

Why is this happening? Any help would be appreciated.

I know now why this is happening. Since the page content I am trying to load into the ID="MainBody" is dependent on the Master Layout page, it makes sense that the navigation bar will be returned as well.  Is there any way I can avoid this?

Changed my views not to be dependent on Master layout page, since I only really want to call the body (html) of each view, and then place it in the ID="MainBody"

Comment: Can you post the raw html that is output when the content has been duplicated please?

Comment: I suppose you should decide on controller that renders your page to return    `PartialView`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your Index controller actions to the following instead:

```
public ActionResult Login() 
{
    return PartialView("Login");
}

public ActionResult Contact() 
{
    return PartialView("Contact");
}

public ActionResult Terms() 
{
    return PartialView("Terms");
}
```

Then remove the directives in your `Login.cshtml`, `Contact.cshtml` and  `Terms.cshtml`:

```
@{    
   Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";   
}
```

Assuming your code is like the above (add custom code or change to your configured code) this will now return partials that do not rely on a master layout.

Comment: Just changing the Actions to return PartialView(), fixes the solution.  Is there anything I should be aware of, since the actual pages are View Pages, and not partial views?

Comment: @akemp IMO you should be fine, there is a very good answer here on the difference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2043394/what-is-the-difference-between-a-view-and-a-partialview-in-asp-net-mvc